# String to Nested Array

Tags: php

Hi i would like to ask if there is any good way to make Nested Array from few strings like in example but when i add NEW STRING it should append

it looks like some kind of tree

String

> TEXT1|||TEXT2|||TEXT3 ....

into

> [TEXT1 => [TEXT2 => [TEXT3] ] ]

new String

> TEXT1|||AAA222|||AAA333

mew array with old one

> [TEXT1 => [TEXT2 => [TEXT3 => null], AAA222 => [AAA333 => null] ] ]

string is generated from this array indexes are levels in "tree"

```
array (size=5)
0 => 
array (size=2)
  'a' => string 'Motoryzacja' (length=11)
  'b' => string '' (length=0)
1 => 
array (size=2)
  'a' => string 'Części samochodowe' (length=20)
  'b' => string '' (length=0)
2 => 
array (size=2)
  'a' => string 'Części karoserii' (length=18)
  'b' => string '' (length=0)
3 => 
array (size=2)
  'a' => string 'Błotniki' (length=9)
  'b' => string '' (length=0)
4 => 
array (size=2)
  'a' => string 'Maski' (length=5)
  'b' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: can you use JSON instead?

Comment: yea if i can convert result to array with this form

Comment: My question is how do you generate your strings? Why not generate JSON instead. `{text1: {text2: {text3: null}, AAA222: {AAA333: null}}}`

Comment: string is generated from array with objects
[OBJECT[DATATEXT] OBJECT2[DATATEXT]]

Comment: how about `json_encode($myArray);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
//recursive function to build the array
function buildArray(Array $input, $output=[]){
  $len = count($input);
  if ($len > 0){
    $key = array_shift($input);
    //if there is more in the array, then we need to continue building our array
    if (($len - 1) > 0){
      $output[$key] = buildArray($input,$output);
    }
    else {
      $output[$key] = NULL;
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
//converts string input with ||| delimiter into nested Array
function stringToArray(String $input){
  $arr = explode('|||', $input);
  $output = buildArray($arr);
  return $output;
}

$arr = stringToArray("TEXT1|||TEXT2|||TEXT3");
$arr2 = stringToArray("TEXT1|||AAA222|||AAA333");
var_dump(array_merge_recursive($arr,$arr2));
```

Comment: perfect solution :)

Comment: perfect solution, love it, thanks you helped so much